# HTML5 Canvas for 3D imported drawing from Catia dassault systemes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, 3d, catia

I am looking for a way to insert 3D drawing made with Catia v5 into a HTML5 canvas!

Something that would let me drag the part and rotate it with a zoom in and out. Is there anything like that already out there??

Catia v5 is a software to draw complex part or assembly for planes in my case.